# Change rails text_field form builder type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, html

I've been looking at the new options available in HTML5 forms, such as declaring input types as "email", "url", and "number", as described [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html).

How can I use these in conjunction with the rails form builders? I have tried

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.email :email, {:placeholder => 'user@domain.com'} %>
<% end %>
```

But that does not work. I've also tried

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, {:placeholder => 'user@domain.com', :type  => :email} %>
<% end %>
```

But the type is still "text" and not overridden. Is it possible, or is this something that will need to be addressed in Rails itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is now an [`email_field` tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/email_field).

Answer (score 7):

Looks like there is currently [an open ticket and patch for adding the HTML5 form input types](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/3646-html5-form-field-helpers-email_field_tag-etc). If you can't wait until the patch is accepted, you could apply the patch locally by freezing the actionpack gems and applying the patch or making an initializer that add the extra methods.

Of course the other option is adding the fields manually without a form helper:

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= tag(:input, {:type => :email, :value => f.object.email} %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply. I added the field manually like you suggested, the code obviously needed a few more attributes e.g.

<%= tag(:input, { :type => :email, :id => 'user_email', :name  => 'user[email]', :placeholder => 'required', :value => f.object.email }) %>